# How can I change my meta_query to SQL wpdb query?

Tags: wpdb, meta-query

I want to extract post related to 3 meta_data fields called bed_value, bath_value, rob_value the variable data is $bedrooms, $bathrooms, &rob, I got some confused with join and like structure. The unworking metaquery is this

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        
        array(
            'key' => 'beds_value',
            'value' => $bedrooms,
            'compare' => '='  
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'baths_value',
            'value' => $bathrooms,
            'compare' => '='    
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'rob_value',
            'value' => $rob,
            'compare' => '='    
        ),          
    ),
);
    
$args = array_merge( $args , $wp_query->query ); 
query_posts( $args );
```

So it is better and easier to do a SQL wpdb query I will change the code. prior wpdb query with `$wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);` does not allow to paginate the results, thats why I tried to change to meta_query I need more knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

Several things, Firstly you can add the following for pagination:

```
'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
```

This removes the need for the array_merge. Otherwise your existing code is fine except for some indentation. I would add the rest of the query though, e.g. defining the post type, the posts per page, etc

Comment: Thanks for this code, fortunatelly the actual code allows to get paged. The main concern on the code above is that only query for one option, some times the user will need to filter data for 2 or 3 options,and now only accepts one filter option; I think is due relation=>'OR' but if I write relation=>'AND' I got no results.   So if it easier to do SQL wpdb query which post paginated and filter data for 3 options I'll be happy. also I will bonus via paypal if code is easy to adapt

Comment: You're using WordPress v3.2.1+ correct?

Comment: Yes, this is the latest version to update and updated on dashboard

Comment: Finally, I found the error... the code to query more than two custom fields are as described above, just is needed to avoid the relation=>'OR' line...

Comment: The search form is quering 3 fields, which needs to be filled to get the values requested, if one field is empty the query mismatch the results and the results are empty due is quering fields with value " " or null. So now I need to change the compare value from '=' to '!=' automatically if a field request is empty

Comment: Or you could just not put that part of the array in the query if the variable is empty?

Comment: I fixed the problem, the query doesn´t need the relation=>'OR' line, so I implement some IF conditionals to chage the value '=' to '!=' according a variable data, so the compare line in not longer an equal or not equal, so this line changes to '=' and '!=' and  also to 'between'according the need of user while quering, I never know which fields the user won´t use, so the values selected will arrange the query automatically.

Comment: So, this question for me is closed...thanks to all!!